# Msbuild Output binaries into another platform

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution that has various projects and some need to be build as x86 for ARM64.
when I build the whole solution for let's say debug/ARM64, some of the binaries go in bin\x86 (for the projects that are being built as x86) and some in bin\ARM64.

Is there a way in MSBUILD to put the binaries in bin\ARM64 even though they can be built as x86 binaries?
OR should I let those build and then copy from bin\x86 to bin\ARM64?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just use `Debug/ARM64` solution platform to build your solution but other projects are built using other platforms, resulting in some projects being built with `x86` and others with `ARM64`.

**Tip 1**

If you want to use **Solution Platform** **Debug/ARM64** to build all projects to `ARM64` once, you should open **Build**--> **Configuration Manager**

Although you have set **Solution Platform** to `ARM64`, you can also change **Project Platform** to others. And ultimately, the build process is still based on the project platform.

[image]

You should change every **project platform** to `ARM64` and then when you build the solution, it will build every project to `ARM64` output folder.

**Tip 2**

**Just a guess, if the guess is wrong, ignore it**

============================

If you build one of your projects, some files are in `bin\ARM64` of the project folder and other binaries are in `bin\x86` of the project folder.

**If so**, you should do a **copy task** for every such project.

```
<Target Name="CopyFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">

        <ItemGroup>
            <Files Include="bin\x86\Debug\xxx.xxx // Any binary files"></Files>
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(Files)"
         DestinationFolder="bin\ARM64\Debug"></Copy>
        
</Target>
```

Add this target in any `xxx.csproj` file of such projects.

==========================================

**Update 1**

**Actually**, there is such option in vs to specify some project files to be compiled in `x86` when building the project with `ARM64`.

Specify which platform to build the project on, and then build all files in the project based on that platform.

So I suggest you could use **Batch Build** to build the project both on `X86` and `ARM64` and then use my `CopyFiles` target to copy these `x86` files into `ARM64` folder during Build.

**First**, add this target into `xxx.csproj` file:

**Then**, Click on **Build** menu-->**Batch Build**

[image]

Click **Build** to execute them at the same time and during the process, the target will be triggered.

**Besides**, perhaps an easier way is to manually copy the files from `x86` folder into `ARM64` folder. This ensures that mistakes are not easily made.

**In addition**, if you still want this automatic option in VS, you could suggest a feature request on our [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8). And the Team will consider your request carefully and give you a satisfactory reply.

Comment: I was basically trying to build a specific project to generate x86 binaries for ARM64. and in order to do that I changed using the Configuration manager which ended up with the projects I changed to x86 in bin\x86 and the rest were in bin\ARM64. If I change as you mentioned in tip1, is there another way to do what I am trying to do (build x86 binaries for ARM64 config)?

Comment: I think you cannot get what you want in VS. I have updated my answer and you can check the suggestions there.